# Heart rate sensor in Gear 3 samsung

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear, tizen-emulator, samsung-gear

I use sample https://resources.developer.samsung.com/050_Samsung_Webinars/Heart_Rate_Monitor_Sample_App_Guide

in Samsung site and download from example.
my issues are, this sample work in simulator but in real device Gear 3 Samsung sensor not work and return zero.

id add this code, but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Tizen 4.0 it might be connected with privacy policy. Please try use [requestPermission](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/ppm.html#PrivacyPrivilegeManager::requestPermission) method. You might check permission by  [checkPermission](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/ppm.html#PrivacyPrivilegeManager::checkPermission)  method. It it return PPM_DENY then modify onhrmControlBtnClick method in your code to

```
/* Defines the error callback. */
function errorCallback(error)
{
    console.log("The following error occurred: " + error.name);
}

/* Defines PermissionSuccessCallback. */
function permissionSuccess(result, privilege)
{
    console.log("User's action for privilege " + privilege + " was to: " + result);
}

function onhrmControlBtnClick() {
    console.log("onhrmControlBtnClick() called...");

    tizen.ppm.requestPermission("http://tizen.org/privilege/healthinfo", permissionSuccess, errorCallback);

    if (hrmControlBtn.innerHTML === TEXT_START){
        console.log("info on button = start");
        startSensor();
    } else {
        console.log("info on button = stop");
        stopSensor();
    }
}
```

I tested on my device and after I accept this privilege, application start working properly.